# Backbone.View with jQuery Editable Plugin 

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, backbone.js

I am trying to use jQuery Editable Plugin in my Backbone.View Object in `Symfony2`.

When I perform `dblclick` on DOM element which `class` is `editable` it turns in input element as I wish.
Then when I perform `keypress` I get three issues:

1. No route found for "POST /[object Object]"    404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
2. the key entry "name" for the model turns to empty string.
3. the view does not change

My goal is to change the backbone.model and then automatically the view.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            "dblclick .editable": "edit",
            "keypress .editable": "updateOnEnter"
        },
       edit: function edit () 
        {
            $(this.el).find(".editable").editable({type:'input'}); // it works
        },

        updateOnEnter: function updateOnEnter (e) 
        {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                this.close();
            }
        },

        close: function close () 
        {
            this._model.set({
                name: $(this.el).find(".editable").text() 
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: There's a few jQuery Editable plugins, which one are you using?

Comment: I am using the following http://pastebin.com/cnRr35Aa

Comment: That's jEditable from http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable and the documentation specifies: "There is only one mandatory parameter. URL where browser posts edited content." ... perhaps this is not the desired jQuery plugin for what you're trying to achieve. Try http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: I don't know but I'm sure the _textfield_ you are seeing when the text becomes editable doesn't match with the selector `.editable`. So the event `keypress` is never captured by Backbone. I suppose it is a brand new DOM element created by the jQuery plugin with its own classes and so on. Try to use the _inspector_ to see if I'm right.

Comment: @fguillen the close function is triggered on key press event, but I get the server error... actually for now I don't want to post any request to the server but just save the result in my Model.

Comment: As @20100 said I think the plugin you are using is doing too much magic for you. Maybe you should try another plugin or rather implement the textfield toggle behavior on your own